# Qt project file: Add libs depending on Kit

Tags: qt, qt-creator, cross-compiling

I have a QT project which runs on x86 linux and ARM linux embedded (yocto).
For each platform I defined a Kit within QtCreator referencing the appropriate compiler etc.

Now I want to add LIBS to my pro file, but I got different libraries on each platform. I didn't find a way to specify the LIBS-directive dependant on the compiling Kit.

I search something like:

```
if (Kit == "Desktop")
    LIBS += ...

if (Kit == "Embedded Yocto")
    LIBS += ...
```

How to achieve this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: There is another interesting answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912778/qtcreator-kit-specific-precompiler-macro-definitions

Comment: alternative by checking OUT_PWD https://stackoverflow.com/a/62452389/5765076

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I scraped together a solution to the OP's problem by using the answer suggested by @vsz in the comments found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912778/qtcreator-kit-specific-precompiler-macro-definitions).

I have two kits, one for the local Desktop and one for the Target_ARM device, and I wanted a way to easily build for both of those without having to specially modify the `.pro` file or anything else.  I followed the linked answer and added the following:

- In my Desktop kit (for both Debug and Release), I added `CONFIG+=Desktop` as an additional `qmake` argument in the `qmake` build step.
- For the Target_ARM kit, I added `CONFIG+=Target_ARM` in the same spot.

Now, this is where things shifted from the linked answer to the OP's problem.  I didn't simply want `#define`ed variables in my code, I wanted to alter the behavior of `qmake` based on the selected kit.  I don't know if the `CONFIG` built-in test function supports block designations or not (ie, `CONFIG { _several lines here_ }`), but it turned out I could copy and paste the `CONFIG` test function in front of each line that I wanted to be conditional; in fact I could string multiple `CONFIG`s together, like this:

```
CONFIG(Desktop, Desktop|Target_ARM):unix:!macx:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += /path/to/Desktop/debug/lib
else:CONFIG(Desktop, Desktop|Target_ARM):unix:!macx:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += /path/to/Destop/release/lib
```

As it suggests, the above statement will run `qmake` with the appropriate `LIBS` path depending on which kit and configuration I have selected.  `Desktop->debug` will generate a Makefile with `/path/to/Desktop/debug/lib` in it whereas `Desktop->release` will generate a Makefile with `/path/to/Desktop/release/lib`.  I have similar statements for the `Target_ARM` kit.  Below is an example of selecting the correct `INCLUDEPATH`: Both tests will evaluate to true when `Target_ARM->release` is selected.

```
CONFIG(Target_ARM, Desktop|Target_ARM):CONFIG(release, debug|release): INCLUDEPATH += /include/path/for/Target_ARM/release
```

In all, I used this method to modify `LIBS, INCLUDEPATH, DEPENDPATH, and PRE_TARGETDEPS`.  I have 4 possible configurations of include paths and libraries depending on which kit I select (`Desktop` or `Target_ARM`) and which build configuration I select (`build` or `release`).  Once this is set up, there is no need to modify the `.pro` file, simply pick your kit, your build configuration, run `qmake`, then rebuild.

I don't know off the top of my head where the `CONFIG+=Desktop` (for example) data is stored, but I would guess in the `.pro.user` file.  So if somebody pulls your `.pro` file from a repo, they may have to initially configure the project in this manner at least once, but not afterwards (as long as the `.pro.user` file persists).  QT should really have an easy mechanism for doing this front-and-center, especially since one of their selling points is multiple-platform integration.  If there's a better way of doing this, I haven't seen it on SO or in the QT documentation yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have all qmake variables here: qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html

You can define a variable

```
KIT = Desktop
#KIT = EmbeddedYocto
```

And use contains function

```
contains( KIT, Desktop ) {
     LIBS += ...
}
contains( KIT, EmbeddedYocto ) {
     LIBS += ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I would change the KIT variable assignment when I change the target platform... Actually I hoped I could query the current selected KIT from QtCreator from the build options.

Answer (score 0):

```
MY_QT_INSTALL_PREFIX=$$[QT_INSTALL_PREFIX]
equals(MY_QT_INSTALL_PREFIX,"C:/Qt/Qt5.3.1/5.3/msvc2010_opengl"){
message($$[QT_INSTALL_PREFIX])
}
```