# QtCreator: kit-specific precompiler macro definitions

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5

I am using QtCreator 3.1.1 to build a cross-platform project, and so I arranged to have different compilation kits for targeting my desktop PC and my BeagleBoneBlack (BBB).

Now I would like to define some macro in qmake project file (`.pro`) which are specific only for a given kit.

In other words I would like do in my `.pro` file something like:

```
if(kit == BBB)
   DEFINES += MY_BBB_MACRO
elseif(kit == Desktop)
   DEFINES += MY_DESKTOP_MACRO
else
   DEFINES += OTHER_MACRO
```

Is is possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I obtained some help on Qt forum (take a look [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/45297/)) about this problem...

Anyway the solution consists in using [qmake built-in test functions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#built-in-test-functions).

Basically I've added some `CONFIG` directive in QtCreator's project management: in the following screenshot you can see for example you can see that I've added `CONFIG+=BBB` in the project configuration for BBB kit; in the same way I've added `CONFIG+=AM335x` and `CONFIG+=Desktop` to AM335x and Desktop kits, respectively...

[image]

Then, in my `.pro` file I've added something like:

[image]

and now in my source code I can use something like `#ifdef PLATFORM_BBB`, `#ifdef PLATFORM_AM335X` and `#ifdef PLATFORM_DESKTOP` for differentiating the program behavior depending on compilation kit.

Comment: Thank you for that hint! Btw, it can be extended by using **"Configure+=Type1 Typ2 Mode1 Mode2 Mode3"** - in _quotes_, so that selections can be made like **CONIFIG(Type1,Type1|Type2):{message(Type11)}** or **CONFIG(Mode1,Mode1|Mode2|Mode3):{message(Mode1)}** etc. etc.

Answer (score 4):

I found another solution.

First, add additional arguments in Projects using `CONFIG+=Variable` name for kit.

[image: screen capture from Project setting]

And in .pro file, write some code like below.

```
Desktop {
    message("Desktop is selected")
}

RPI {
    message("rpi is selected")
    target.path = /home/pi
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

If you look at the general message tab, you can see that the setting works well.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this method to add a unit test build, adding CONFIG+=_TEST to my unit testing builds. I've then added:   _TEST { DEFINTES += _TEST }    to the .pro, but all builds seem to act as if _TEST is defined. Any thoughts?