# Using conditional expression for Kits in Qt qmake

Tags: qt, compilation, makefile, qmake

I have a qmake (Qt 4.8.6) .pro file and I need to add conditional expressions based on the compiled kits:

I currently have 2 Kits (with different compilers), one for the *Desktop* and one for the *Embedded Platform*, my application is linked to some libraries, that are compiled both for Desktop and for Embedded in two different folders.

So what I'd like to achieve is:

```
unix { embedded-platform { LIBS+= -lonearm -ltwoarm etc... }}
unix { desktop { LIBS += -lonex86 -ltwox86 etc... }}
```

I read the docs carefully but **I can't figure out how to be aware of what kit is being built** from inside the .pro.

I already tried the solution proposed here https://forum.qt.io/topic/52954/solved-qmake-how-to-achieve-kit-detection-and-automatic-conditional-linking/3 but it does not solve my problem as there is no way to discriminate between custom Kits on the same platform (the two compilers are g++ and arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++).

Any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3056901/999943

Comment: @phyatt it's the same solution from the link I posted...it seems not to discern between differents linux-g++ (like in this case)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to switch based on the compiler, too.  The keywords to use are listed in the mkspecs folder.

Looking at the `mkspecs` on my computer for one of the Qt 5.4 kits, it had the following folders:

```
aix-g++
aix-g++-64
aix-xlc
aix-xlc-64
android-g++
blackberry-armle-v7-qcc
blackberry-armv7le-qcc
blackberry-x86-qcc
common
common/aix
common/android
common/c89
common/ios
common/ios/GLES2
common/mac
common/nacl
common/posix
common/qnx
common/wince
common/winrt_winphone
common/winrt_winphone/assets
common/winrt_winphone/manifests
common/winrt_winphone/manifests/8.0
common/winrt_winphone/manifests/8.1
common/winrt_winphone/manifests/8.1_wp
cygwin-g++
darwin-g++
devices
devices/blackberry-playbook-armle-v7-qcc
devices/blackberry-playbook-armv7le-qcc
devices/blackberry-playbook-x86-qcc
devices/common
devices/linux-archos-gen8-g++
devices/linux-arm-amlogic-8726M-g++
devices/linux-arm-hisilicon-hix5hd2-g++
devices/linux-arm-trident-pnx8473-g++
devices/linux-beagleboard-g++
devices/linux-imx53qsb-g++
devices/linux-imx6-g++
devices/linux-mipsel-broadcom-97425-g++
devices/linux-rasp-pi-g++
devices/linux-sh4-stmicro-ST7108-g++
devices/linux-sh4-stmicro-ST7540-g++
devices/linux-snowball-g++
devices/linux-tegra2-g++
features
features/android
features/data
features/data/android
features/data/cmake
features/data/headersclean
features/mac
features/qpa
features/unix
features/win32
features/winrt
freebsd-g++
freebsd-g++46
freebsd-icc
hpux-acc
hpux-acc-64
hpux-acc-o64
hpux-g++
hpux-g++-64
hpuxi-acc-32
hpuxi-acc-64
hpuxi-g++-64
hurd-g++
irix-cc
irix-cc-64
irix-g++
irix-g++-64
linux-arm-gnueabi-g++
linux-clang
linux-clang-libc++
linux-cxx
linux-g++
linux-g++-32
linux-g++-64
linux-icc
linux-icc-32
linux-icc-64
linux-kcc
linux-llvm
linux-lsb-g++
linux-pgcc
lynxos-g++
macx-clang
macx-clang-32
macx-g++
macx-g++-32
macx-g++40
macx-g++42
macx-icc
macx-ios-clang
macx-ios-clang/features
macx-llvm
macx-xcode
modules
netbsd-g++
openbsd-g++
qnx-armle-v7-qcc
qnx-armv7le-qcc
qnx-x86-qcc
sco-cc
sco-g++
solaris-cc
solaris-cc-64
solaris-cc-64-stlport
solaris-cc-stlport
solaris-g++
solaris-g++-64
tru64-cxx
tru64-g++
unixware-cc
unixware-g++
unsupported
unsupported/android-g++
unsupported/freebsd-clang
unsupported/integrity-ghs
unsupported/linux-armcc
unsupported/linux-host-g++
unsupported/linux-scratchbox2-g++
unsupported/nacl-g++
unsupported/nacl64-g++
unsupported/qnx-X11-g++
unsupported/vxworks-ppc-dcc
unsupported/vxworks-ppc-g++
unsupported/vxworks-simpentium-dcc
unsupported/vxworks-simpentium-g++
unsupported/win32-msvc2003
win32-g++
win32-icc
win32-msvc2005
win32-msvc2008
win32-msvc2010
win32-msvc2012
win32-msvc2013
wince60standard-armv4i-msvc2005
wince60standard-x86-msvc2005
wince70embedded-armv4i-msvc2008
wince70embedded-x86-msvc2008
winphone-arm-msvc2012
winphone-arm-msvc2013
winphone-x86-msvc2012
winphone-x86-msvc2013
winrt-arm-msvc2012
winrt-arm-msvc2013
winrt-x64-msvc2012
winrt-x64-msvc2013
winrt-x86-msvc2012
winrt-x86-msvc2013
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: But should I manually add a new mkspec to the mkspecs folder based on the kit I created in Qt Creator? I can't find anything related to my kit so far...

Comment: I haven't built a custom kit before, so I can't say.  In the build output for the custom kit, did it generate a mkspecs folder?  You can probably merge it with the other mkspecs folder if needed...

Answer (score 1):

I have not enough reputation to comment phyatts answer, which is basically correct. 
For debugging purposes you can add

```
message($$QMAKESPEC)
```

to your pro file to get the precise name of the compiler currently used for building your project. This gives something like

> /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/**linux-g++**

where the bold part is the scope value. The mkspecs should be given with the kit, e.g included in the toolchain you've installed. Switch the kit to get the name of the second compiler.Then use the scope values in line with

```
linux-g++: { message( "found g++" ) }
linux-gnueabi-oe-g++: { message( "found g++ embedded" ) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (especially when there no distinction between two compilers) one can use [OUT_PWD](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#out-pwd) variable to [find](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#find-variablename-substr) particular sub string (pattern) in ouput folder name (that contains kit name from [general settings](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html#specifying-kit-settings) by default if not modified).

```
OUT_PWD = $$OUT_PWD
X2_PWD = $$find(OUT_PWD, "Linux_X2")
!isEmpty(X2_PWD) {
    message("Compiling for X2 device")
    # LIBS += ...
}
```

I did not get why **find** can't work with $$OUT_PWD directly so just make intermediate variable. I've test this only with qt5.

And of course other vars, for instance [QMAKESPEC](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-environment-reference.html#qmakespec) could be also be easily used too.